# How do I convert double to string using only math.h?

Tags: c++, c, floating-point

I am trying to convert a double to a string in a native NT application, i.e. an application that only depends on `ntdll.dll`. Unfortunately, ntdll's version of `vsnprintf` does not support `%f` et al., forcing me to implement the conversion on my own.

The aforementioned `ntdll.dll` exports only a few of the `math.h` functions (`floor`, `ceil`, `log`, `pow`, ...). However, I am reasonably sure that I can implement any of the unavailable `math.h` functions if necessary.

There is an implementation of floating point conversion in GNU's libc, but the code is extremely dense and difficult to comprehent (the GNU indentation style does not help here).

I've already implemented the conversion by normalizing the number (i.e. multiplying/dividing the number by 10 until it's in the interval `[1, 10)`) and then generating each digit by cutting the integral part off with `modf` and multiplying the fractional part by 10. This works, but there is a loss of precision (only the first 15 digits are correct). The loss of precision is, of course, inherent to the algorithm.

I'd settle with 17 digits, but an algorithm that would be able to generate an arbitrary number of digits correctly would be preferred.

Could you please suggest an algorithm or point me to a good resource?

Comment: "the GNU indentation style does not help here": use indent ( http://indent.isidore-it.eu/beautify.html ), there's a version for Windows ( http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/indent.htm ) which I haven't tested.

Comment: Thank you, pmg, the indentation is not the only flaw of the code in question, unfortunately.

Comment: I've written an article about the inaccurate conversion method you describe -- in case, one year later, you still care: http://www.exploringbinary.com/quick-and-dirty-floating-point-to-decimal-conversion/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After a lot of research, I found a paper titled [Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately](http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~burger/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf). It uses exact rational arithmetic to avoid precision loss. It cites a little older paper: [How to Print Floating-Point Numbers Accurately](http://portal.acm.org/citation.cfm?id=93559), which however seems to require ACM subscription to access.

Since the former paper was reprinted in 2006, I am inclined to believe that it is still current. The exact rational arithmetic (which requires dynamic allocation) seems to be a necessary evil.

Comment: The link is broken for first URL. Use this instead:
http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.67.4438&rep=rep1&type=pdf

Comment: And here is the full C code implementation of this algorithm on SourceForge: http://code.google.com/p/double-conversion/downloads/detail?name=double-conversion-1.1.5.tar.gz&can=2&q=

Answer (score 5):

Double-precision numbers do not have more than 15 significant (decimal) figures of precision. There is absolutely no way you can get "an arbitrary number of digits correctly"; `double`s are not bignums.

Since you say you're happy with 17 significant figures, use `long double`; on Windows, I think, that will give you 19 significant figures.

Comment: Chris, thank you for answering. To round-trim double->string->double you definitely need 17 digits (see Golberg for proof: http://docs.sun.com/source/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html#1251). Moreover, a double represents a unique rational number, which may need an infinite number of decimal digits to represent precisely.

Comment: You can't use doubles to represent rational numbers with precision. Instead, you have to have two integers (possibly longs), to represent the numerator and denominator independently.

Comment: As for roundtripping, you should serialise your double in binary form, not decimal.

Comment: Chris, I'm not trying to represent a rational number using a double. Instead I *have* a double, which represents some rational number with possibly infinite decimal representation (that's why it is reasonable to require an arbitrary number of digits from the conversion).

Comment: A double *doesn't* have arbitrary precision. You're losing precision, because *a double is incapable of representing it*.

Comment: grayfade, I've never said that doubles have arbitrary precision. They, of course, are limited to 52 binary digits (well, 53 actually). However, when you convert this binary number (with at most 53 digits) to decimal, you may get an infinite number of decimal digits.

Comment: No, you won't get an infinite number of decimal digits. Why? Because no ratio where the denominator is a power of two ever gives a recurring decimal representation.

Comment: @Avakar: seems you need a question on "why don't I get an infinite number of decimal digits with a floating point representation?" :)

Comment: Oh... my bad, you're right :) Scratch the word infinite. The number of decimal digits, however, may still be pretty high.

Comment: xtofl, haha, granted, that was a pretty stupid mistake. :) The original question remains valid though.

Comment: It may be high, but if all you care about is roundtripping, print your digits in hex. Seriously, you will lose a lot less precision that way.

Comment: Chris, I don't care just about round-tripping. I'm trying to emulate the behavior of `printf`, which on msvc does give 17 digits that can be used to round-trip. gcc can give arbitrary number of digits.

Comment: If you are really emulating printf, you won't usually get that many digits. I don't know whether the number of digits by default is standarized or not, but the general usage will print just a few of them (and really few for what matters)

Comment: dribeas, the default precision for `%f` is set to 6, but you can set precision manually: `printf("%.17f", 1.1);`.

Answer (score 4):

I've thought about this a bit more.  You lose precision because you normalize by multiplying by some power of 10 (you chose [1,10) rather than [0,1), but that's a minor detail).  If you did so with a power of 2, you'd lose no precision, but then you'd get "decimal digits"*2^e; you could implement bcd arithmetic and compute the product yourself, but that doesn't sound like fun.

I'm pretty confident that you could split the double `g=m*2^e` into two parts: `h=floor(g*10^k)` and `i=modf(g*10^k)` for some k, and then separately convert to decimal digits and then stitch them together, but how about a simpler approach: use "long double" (80 bits, but I've heard that Visual C++ may not support it?) with your current approach and stop after 17 digits.

[`_gcvt`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/26cdxcyz(VS.80).aspx) should do it (edit - it's not in ntdll.dll, it's in some msvcrt*.dll?)

As for decimal digits of precision, [IEEE binary64](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-2008) has 52 binary digits.  52*log10(2)=15.65... (edit: as you pointed out, to round trip, you need more than 16 digits)

Comment: Thank you wrang-wrang. Unfortunately, I don't have `_gcvt` available in native. Regarding the 15.65 value, it only means that you can represent a number with 15 digits precisely in double. For round-tripping, however, you need 17 digits.

Comment: I agree that more than log10(2)*d decimal digits are needed to exactly represent a d-bit fraction on [0,1), e.g. 1/16 = (.1111)_2 = .9375, which is 4 decimal digits for 4 binary digits.

Comment: Yes, I suppose having greater precision would give me those 17 digits. Unfortunately, `long double` is equivalent to `double` in msvc (at least in msvc9).

Comment: Regarding converting integral and fractional parts separately: remember that doubles can go as high as 1.e308. I'll lose the 17th digit as soon as I perform the first non-power-of-two multiplication.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <cstdint>

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Return number of decimal-digits of a given unsigned-integer
// N is unit8_t/uint16_t/uint32_t/uint64_t
template <class N> inline uint8_t GetUnsignedDecDigits(const N n)
{
    static_assert(std::numeric_limits<N>::is_integer && !std::numeric_limits<N>::is_signed,
                  "GetUnsignedDecDigits: unsigned integer type expected"                   );

    const uint8_t anMaxDigits[]= {3, 5, 8, 10, 13, 15, 17, 20};
    const uint8_t nMaxDigits   = anMaxDigits[sizeof(N)-1];

    uint8_t nDigits=  1;
    N       nRoof  = 10;

    while ((n >= nRoof) && (nDigits<nMaxDigits))
    {
        nDigits++;
        nRoof*= 10;
    }

    return nDigits;
}

// --------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Convert floating-point value to NULL-terminated string represention
TCHAR* DoubleToStr(double f       ,  // [i  ]
                   TCHAR* pczStr  ,  // [i/o] caller should allocate enough space
                   int    nDigitsI,  // [i  ] digits of integer    part including sign / <1: auto
                   int    nDigitsF ) // [i  ] digits of fractional part                / <0: auto
{
    switch (_fpclass(f))
    {
        case _FPCLASS_SNAN:
        case _FPCLASS_QNAN: _tcscpy_s(pczStr, 5, _T("NaN" )); return pczStr;
        case _FPCLASS_NINF: _tcscpy_s(pczStr, 5, _T("-INF")); return pczStr;
        case _FPCLASS_PINF: _tcscpy_s(pczStr, 5, _T("+INF")); return pczStr;
    }

    if (nDigitsI> 18) nDigitsI= 18;  if (nDigitsI< 1) nDigitsI= -1;
    if (nDigitsF> 18) nDigitsF= 18;  if (nDigitsF< 0) nDigitsF= -1;

    bool bNeg= (f<0);
    if (f<0)
        f= -f;

    int nE= 0;                                  // exponent (displayed if != 0)

    if ( ((-1 == nDigitsI) && (f >= 1e18              )) ||   // large value: switch to scientific representation
         ((-1 != nDigitsI) && (f >= pow(10., nDigitsI)))    )
    {
       nE= (int)log10(f);
       f/= (double)pow(10., nE);

       if (-1 != nDigitsF)
           nDigitsF= __max(nDigitsF, nDigitsI+nDigitsF-(bNeg?2:1)-4);

       nDigitsI= (bNeg?2:1);
    }
    else if (f>0)
    if ((-1 == nDigitsF) && (f <= 1e-10))       // small value: switch to scientific representation
    {
        nE= (int)log10(f)-1;
        f/= (double)pow(10., nE);

       if (-1 != nDigitsF)
           nDigitsF= __max(nDigitsF, nDigitsI+nDigitsF-(bNeg?2:1)-4);

        nDigitsI= (bNeg?2:1);
    }

    double fI;
    double fF= modf(f, &fI);                    // fI: integer part, fF: fractional part

    if (-1 == nDigitsF)                         // figure out number of meaningfull digits in fF
    {
        double fG, fGI, fGF;
        do
        {
            nDigitsF++;
            fG = fF*pow(10., nDigitsF);
            fGF= modf(fG, &fGI);
        }
        while (fGF > 1e-10);
    }

    const double afPower10[20]= {1e0 , 1e1 , 1e2 , 1e3 , 1e4 , 1e5 , 1e6 , 1e7 , 1e8 , 1e9 , 
                                 1e10, 1e11, 1e12, 1e13, 1e14, 1e15, 1e16, 1e17, 1e18, 1e19 };

    uint64_t uI= (uint64_t)round(fI                    );
    uint64_t uF= (uint64_t)round(fF*afPower10[nDigitsF]);

    if (uF)
        if (GetUnsignedDecDigits(uF) > nDigitsF)    // X.99999 was rounded to X+1
        {
            uF= 0;
            uI++;

            if (nE)
            {
                uI/= 10;
                nE++;
            }
        }

    uint8_t nRealDigitsI= GetUnsignedDecDigits(uI);
    if (bNeg)
        nRealDigitsI++;

    int nPads= 0;

    if (-1 != nDigitsI)
    {
        nPads= nDigitsI-nRealDigitsI;

        for (int i= nPads-1; i>=0; i--)         // leading spaces
            pczStr[i]= _T(' ');
    }

    if (bNeg)                                   // minus sign
    {
        pczStr[nPads]= _T('-');
        nRealDigitsI--;
        nPads++;
    }

    for (int j= nRealDigitsI-1; j>=0; j--)      // digits of integer    part
    {
        pczStr[nPads+j]= (uint8_t)(uI%10) + _T('0');
        uI /= 10;
    }

    nPads+= nRealDigitsI;

    if (nDigitsF)
    {
        pczStr[nPads++]= _T('.');               // decimal point
        for (int k= nDigitsF-1; k>=0; k--)      // digits of fractional part
        {
            pczStr[nPads+k]= (uint8_t)(uF%10)+ _T('0');
            uF /= 10;
        }
    }

    nPads+= nDigitsF;

    if (nE)
    {
        pczStr[nPads++]= _T('e');               // exponent sign

        if (nE<0)
        {
            pczStr[nPads++]= _T('-');
            nE= -nE;
        }
        else
            pczStr[nPads++]= _T('+');

        for (int l= 2; l>=0; l--)               // digits of exponent
        {
            pczStr[nPads+l]= (uint8_t)(nE%10) + _T('0');
            nE /= 10;
        }

        pczStr[nPads+3]= 0;
    }
    else
        pczStr[nPads]= 0;

    return pczStr;
}
```

Comment: These two lines will never execute. They're mutually exclusive with the outer "if" test. Bug? 

if (-1 != nDigitsF)
            nDigitsF= max(nDigitsF, nDigitsI+nDigitsF-(bNeg?2:1)-4);

Comment: Also, what is "afPower10"?

Comment: @srm: Why are these lines mutually exclusive? the outer if is about nDigitsI and the inner if is about nDigitsF.

Comment: my mistake. I got the I and F messed up while reading the code. I know it would expand the text, but variable names that are almost identical except for a single letter are really hard to follow. I found it easier to follow some of your logic once I text substituted "Integral" for "I" and "Fraction" for "F". That preserves the "both are the same length" quality of the variable names and provides more of a guard against mis-reading an "I" as an "F" or vice versa. I realize that English majors will cringe that I used the adjective form for I and the noun form for F. :-)

Answer (score 2):

A complete implementation of the C code for the fastest known (as of today) algorithm:
http://code.google.com/p/double-conversion/downloads/list

It even includes a test suite.

This is the C code behind the algorithm described in this PDF:
Printing Floating-Point Numbers Quickly and Accurately
http://www.cs.indiana.edu/~burger/FP-Printing-PLDI96.pdf

Answer (score 1):

Does `vsnprintf` supports I64?

```
double x = SOME_VAL; // allowed to be from -1.e18 to 1.e18
bool sign = (SOME_VAL < 0);
if ( sign ) x = -x;
__int64 i = static_cast<__int64>( x );
double xm = x - static_cast<double>( i );
__int64 w = static_cast<__int64>( xm*pow(10.0, DIGITS_VAL) ); // DIGITS_VAL indicates how many digits after the decimal point you want to get

char out[100];
vsnprintf( out, sizeof out, "%s%I64.%I64", (sign?"-":""), i, w );
```

Another option is to try [to find implementation of `gcvt`](http://google.com/codesearch?&lr=&q=gcvt).

Comment: That's pretty fast and simple, except it fails when the exponent is large or small, or the number is negative.

Comment: Kirill, thank you. Unfortunately, I need to support numbers up to and above 1.e308 :)

Comment: @avakar, then my answer is not suitable to you :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you looked at the [uClibc implementation](http://git.uclibc.org/uClibc/tree/libc/stdio/_vfprintf.c) of `printf`?

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, caf. I've looked into it and it seems they use similar algorithm as I do, although they extract more than one digit at each step. I'm inclined to believe that they lose precision the same way I do.