# How to convert a double to a string without using the CRT

Tags: c++, string, double, printf, crt

My question has no practical application. I'm just interested. Suppose, I have a double value and I want to obtain its string representation similarly to the `printf` function. How would I do that without the C runtime library? Let's suppose I'm on the x86 architecture.

Comment: It very much depends on the amount of imprecision you're willing to tolerate. One of my (unanswered) questions may be of some help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1434511/how-do-i-convert-double-to-string-using-only-math-h

Comment: Yes, looks very-very similar. Have you found the solution?

Comment: There is an answer by me which links to two papers. Both, however, require arbitrary-precision integer arithmetic. As far as I know, there is no other way to recover all 17 digits (but I'd like to be proven wrong).

Comment: Right, no practical application, yawn.  Why don't you start a CodeGolf?

Comment: nobugz, it may have no practical application for the OP and for you, but it certainly once had for me.

Comment: I stumbled into this question since I was curious to see the solution to the question as I interpreted it: How to convert a double to a string without using the Cathode Ray Tube.  :-)

Answer (score 2):

Given that you state your question has no practical application, I figure you're trying to learn about floating point number representations.

Thus, if you're looking for a solution without using ***any*** library support, start with the [format specification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_754-1985). From that you can discern the various "special" values (Infinity, NAN, etc) as well as decoding/calculating the actual numeric value. Once you have the significand and exponent, you know where to put the decimal point. You'll have to write your own [itoa](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Itoa) type routine. For radices which are a power of two, this can be as simple as a lookup table. For decimal, you'll have to do a little extra math.

Answer (score 0):

you can get all values on left side by (double % 10) and then divide by 10 every time.
they will be in right to left.

to get values on right of dot you have to multiply by 10 and then (double % 10). they will be in left-to-right.

Comment: From my experience, I can tell you that you'll only get about 13 digits (out of 17) right.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it simply with a "close enough" result, see my article http://www.exploringbinary.com/quick-and-dirty-floating-point-to-decimal-conversion/ . It describes a simple program that uses floating-point to convert from floating-point to decimal, and explains why that approach can never be accurate for all conversions. (The program doesn't do decimal rounding like printf, but that should be easy enough to add.)